# I am building shiny dashboard where I need to render table dynamically..my code below

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to build shiny dashboard application.

Within the application, I need to render a table dynamically. 
When I load the application, I am not receiving the tabular output.

I have split the code into three files: `global.R`, `ui.R`, and `server.R`

**global.R**

```
my_data <- head(mtcars)
```

**ui.R**

```
tabItem(tabName = "impRels",
        fluidRow(
                 box(DT::dataTableOutput("table1"))
              )
)
```

**server.R**

```
output$table1 <- DT::renderDataTable({
   datatable(my_data)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplified, as a start. You might want to work on your UI, though.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

my_data <- head(mtcars)

ui <- shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
   fluidRow( dataTableOutput("table1") ) 
  )
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session){
  output$table1 <- renderDataTable({ datatable(my_data) })
})

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Comment: this works but when I am trying to put the same piece of code in shiny dashboard then no output is coming.

Comment: UI code    # Thirds tab content
      tabItem(tabName = "impRels",
              fluidPage(
                fluidRow( dataTableOutput("table1") ) 
              )
      )

Comment: server code:: my_data<- head(mtcars)  output$table1 <- renderDataTable({ datatable(my_data) })

Comment: the rendering table not working when I am putting the code inside tabItem in ui

Comment: @Ruma Sinha . Seems that you want to work with shinydashboard on the client side. Please follow these instructions here. https://rstudio.github.io/shinydashboard/get_started.html